# run lm command with zeros and N/A in database

Tags: r

I´m currently working with r. My database has a lot of zeros and N/A, so when I run the lm() command with a log-log model it doesn´t works. Any advice?

Comment: It is good practice to provide some code and a reproducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best answer but it got me working: I store the results of my database in a new variable, and i prune all missing values out (in my case, cells that literally have nothing in them, or ""), like this:

```
library(RODBC) # database on a SQL box
library(tidyverse)
myConnection <- odbcConnect("name_of_your_DNS") # I create a DSN first
Data <- sqlFetch(channel = myConnection, sqtable = "name_of_your_table")

empty_as_na <- function(x) {
  if("factor" %in% class(x)) x <- as.character(x) ## since ifelse wont work with factors
  ifelse(as.character(x)!="", x, NA)}
Data <- Data %>% mutate_all(funs(empty_as_na))
```

you might consider experimenting with adding this after loading the RODBC library:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```